# How to draw multiple arrows indicating different nodes using tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

How to write this diagram using tikz matrix?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A pure Ti*k*Z solution, using `matrix of math nodes`. The hardest part is to draw the double arrows. Originally I used `shift` to change the starting points and the ending points of the arrows, but it is not really good and it is a pain to do so for many arrows. Here I use [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)'s nice style in his suggestion in the comments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,matrix,calc}
\newcommand\psr{\mathrm{PSR}}
\newcommand\pr{\mathrm{PR}}
\newcommand\pst{\mathrm{PST}}
\tikzset{ % Double arrow style thanks to marmot!
    shifted by/.style={
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)
        }
    }, 
    shifted by/.default=2pt, 
    back and forth between/.style args={#1 and #2}{
        insert path={ 
            #1 edge[->,shifted by] #2 #2 edge[->,shifted by] #1
        }
    }
} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=1cm,
    column sep=1.5cm]
{%
\psr_0 & \pst_0 & \omega\pst_0\\
\psr_1 & \pst_1 & \omega\pst_1\\
\psr_2 & \pst_2 & \omega\pst_2\\
\pr_3  & \pst_3 & \omega\pst_3\\
       & \pst_4 & \omega\pst_4\\
};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} \draw[->] (m-\i-2)--(m-\i-3);
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3,4} \draw[->] (m-\j-2)--(m-\i-2);
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3} {
    \draw[->] (m-\j-3)--(m-\i-3);
    \draw[back and forth between={(m-\i-1.south east) and (m-\j-2.north west)}];
    \draw (m-\i-1)--(m-\i-2);
}
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2} {
    \draw[->] (m-\j-1)--(m-\i-1);
    \draw[
        postaction=decorate,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {
                \draw[-] (-3pt,-5pt)--(3pt, 5pt);
            }
        },
        ->
    ] (m-\j-3)--(m-\i-2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add styles from `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{shifted by/.style={to path={($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$) 
-- ($(\tikztotarget)!#1!-90:(\tikztostart)$)}},
shifted by/.default=2pt,
back and forth between/.style args={#1 and #2}{insert path={
#1 edge[-latex,shifted by] #2 #2 edge[-latex,shifted by] #1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) edge[->,shifted by=2pt] (2,1) (2,1) edge[->,shifted by=2pt] (0,0);
\draw[back and forth between={(0,-2) and (2,-1)}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: @marmot Great! Thank you very much - this approach is far better than mine. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

small modification of @JouleV [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483633/how-to-draw-multiple-arrows-indicating-different-nodes-using-tikz-matrix/483683#483683). without the `tikz` library `decorations.markings` and using `canvas transform` for shifting of arrows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand\psr{\mathrm{PSR}}
\newcommand\pr{\mathrm{PR}}
\newcommand\pst{\mathrm{PST}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
                    ]
\matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=1cm,
    column sep=1.5cm]
{%
\psr_0 & \pst_0 & \omega\pst_0\\
\psr_1 & \pst_1 & \omega\pst_1\\
\psr_2 & \pst_2 & \omega\pst_2\\
\pr_3  & \pst_3 & \omega\pst_3\\
       & \pst_4 & \omega\pst_4\\
};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5}
    \draw[->] (m-\i-2)--(m-\i-3);
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3,4}
    \draw[->] (m-\j-2)--(m-\i-2);
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3} {
    \draw[->] (m-\j-3)--(m-\i-3);
    \draw[->,transform canvas={shift={( 1pt, 1pt)}}] (m-\i-1.south east)--(m-\j-2.north west);
    \draw[<-,transform canvas={shift={(-1pt,-1pt)}}] (m-\i-1.south east)--(m-\j-2.north west);
    \draw (m-\i-1)--(m-\i-2);
}
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2} {
    \draw[->] (m-\j-1)-- (m-\i-1);
    \draw[->] (m-\j-3)-- node[sloped] {/} (m-\i-2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I did not know of `canvas transform` before. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much, i also up-vote your answer. in my country we have the saying: man is learning his whole life, so i learn something from your answers too :-)

Comment: @JouleV `transform canvas` has many side effects and should IMHO not be used here at all.

Comment: @marmot, i disagree. in this particular case its use not arm anything. however, it should not be used for moving something "outside" of defined nodes borders or coordinates. in this cases its elements are not considered in bounding box.